# Angular 2 Router - 2nd Level Links Not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

My Angular 2 site has got a main navigation and all these routes are working no problem... however i have inner pages that are 1 level down from the main Routes and they simply dont traverse or even recognise the change when the link is clicked.. the url bar stays the same and the page just goes blank.  Here are my main files of interest:

package.json --

```
            {
              "name": "",
              "version": "",
              "author": "",
              "description": "",
              "main": "src/tmp/app/main.js",
              "scripts": {
                "postinstall": "typings install",
                "start": "gulp",
                "test": "gulp test",
                "coveralls": "node ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js < ./report/remap/lcov.info"
              },
              "dependencies": {
                "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
                "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
                "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
                "font-awesome": "^4.6.1",
                "jquery": "^2.2.3",
                "lodash": "^4.13.1",
                "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
                "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
                "systemjs": "^0.19.29",
                "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "browser-sync": "^2.12.8",
                "codelyzer": "0.0.19",
                "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.2.0",
                "del": "~2.2.0",
                "glob": "^7.0.3",
                "gulp": "^3.9.1",
                "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
                "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
                "gulp-if": "~2.0.1",
                "gulp-protractor": "^2.3.0",
                "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
                "gulp-rev": "^7.0.0",
                "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.3",
                "gulp-sass": "^2.3.1",
                "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
                "gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
                "gulp-typescript": "~2.13.4",
                "gulp-uglify": "~1.5.3",
                "gulp-useref": "~3.1.0",
                "gulp-watch": "^4.3.6",
                "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
                "karma": "~0.13.22",
                "karma-coverage": "~1.0.0",
                "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
                "karma-jasmine": "~1.0.2",
                "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0.0",
                "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
                "ngstarter-systemjs-tasks": "1.0.0-rc.1",
                "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
                "remap-istanbul": "~0.6.4",
                "require-dir": "~0.3.0",
                "run-sequence": "^1.2.1",
                "traceur": "~0.0.110",
                "tslint": "^3.10.2",
                "typings": "^1.0.4",
                "yargs": "^4.7.1"
              }
            }
```

init.ts - all the routes defined

```
            import {Component} from '@angular/core';
            import {HomepageListComponent} from '../Homepage/list/HomepageListComponent';
            import {ProjectsListComponent} from '../Projects/list/ProjectListComponent';
            import {ProjectDetailsComponent} from '../Projects/details/ProjectDetailsComponent';
            import {ContactComponent} from '../Contact/ContactComponent';
            import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
            declare var jQuery: any;



            @RouteConfig([
                { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomepageListComponent },
                { path: '/project', name: 'Project', component: ProjectsListComponent },
                { path: '/project/:slug', name: 'ProjectDetail', component: ProjectDetailsComponent },
                { path: '/contact', name: 'Contact', component: ContactComponent },
               // { path: '/', name: 'root', redirectTo: ['/Home'] }
            ])

            @Component({
                selector: 'init',
                templateUrl: './app/components/init/init.html',
                directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
            })

            export class InitComponent {

                title: string;

                constructor() {
                    this.title = 'App title';
                }

                pageChanged(e) {
                    jQuery(document.body).removeClass('navigation-is-open');
                    console.log(e);
                }

            }
```

projectsListComponent.ts - the main component which displays all the projects and also specified what second level route to call using RouterLink

```
            import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
            import {ProjectsMainApi} from '../../../services/projects-main';
            import 'rxjs/Rx';
            import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
            import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

            declare var jQuery: any;

            @Component({
                selector: 'projects',
                template:
                    `<a class="project-display" *ngFor="let projekt of project | async" [routerLink]="['ProjectDetail', {slug: projekt.slug }]" >
                    </a>`,
                directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
            })

            export class ProjectsListComponent implements OnInit {

                elementRef: ElementRef;
                project: Observable<any>;

                constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, private _projectsmainapi: ProjectsMainApi) {
                    this.elementRef = elementRef;
                    this.project    = this._projectsmainapi.project$;
                    this._projectsmainapi.getProjectsMain();
                }
                ngOnInit() {
                    this.project.subscribe(() => {

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            jQuery('.projects').projects();
                        }, 0);

                    });
                }
            }
```

The internal projectsDetailsComponent.ts -- html has been simplified so as to show the inner workings of the component

```
            import {Component} from '@angular/core';
            import {ProjectsMainApi} from '../../../services/projects-main';
            import { RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

            declare var jQuery: any;

            interface ProjectResult {
                project: Object;
            }

            @Component({
            selector: 'projects',
            template: `<h1>I am a single page for a specific project </h1>`,
                directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
            })

            export class ProjectDetailsComponent  {
                project: Object = {};
                constructor(private _api: ProjectsMainApi, private _params: RouteParams) {
                    this._api.getSinglePortfolio(_params.get('slug')).then(
                        (res: ProjectResult) => {
                            this.project = res.project[0];
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.error(error);
                    });
                }
            }
```

And the services file that pulls the project info in..

```
            import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
            import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
            import {IProjectsMain} from '../interfaces/AvailableInterfaces';
            import 'rxjs/Rx';
            import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
            import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
            import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
            import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

            @Injectable()
            export class ProjectsMainApi {
                apiUrl: string = 'http://www.siteexample.com/api/projects';
                headers: Headers = new Headers;
                project$: Observable<IProjectsMain[]>;
                private _ProjectsMainObserver: Observer<IProjectsMain[]>;
                private _dataStore: {
                    project: IProjectsMain[]
                };

                constructor(private _http: Http) {
                    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                    this.project$ = new Observable<IProjectsMain[]>(observer => this._ProjectsMainObserver = observer).share();
                    this._dataStore = { project: [] };
                }

                public getProjectsMain() {
                    this._http.get(this.apiUrl).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
                        this._dataStore.project = data.project;
                        this._ProjectsMainObserver.next(this._dataStore.project);
                    }, error => console.log('Could not load projects.'),
                    () => 'done');
                }

                public getSinglePortfolio(id) {
                   console.log('the id is  ' + this.apiUrl + '/' + id);
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        this._http.get(this.apiUrl + '/' + id).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
                            (res) => {
                                resolve(res);
                            }, (error) => {
                                reject(error);
                            });
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where are the links and how do they look like?

Comment: If you look at the a element in the projecListComponent.ts that I provided above you will see it in routerlink

Comment: The only occurence of "RouterLink" is in the text "route to call using RouterLink"

Comment: Look at the ngFor in the code block below that and you will see [routerLink]=

Comment: Sorry, I used browser search (find in page) but it didn't show it :-/

Answer (score 0):

It's lots of code and I didn't try to fully understand all you provided, but from what I found I think it should be

```
[routerLink]="['../ProjectDetail', {slug: projekt.slug }]"
```

Comment: I know its a lot :) I tried that and it didnt work.. the weird thing is it used to work, but i have now compiled all my ts files into one and also all of angular2s libs into another file and everything works except deeper routing.. weird

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: Not at the moment, it would take a while to reproduce the site in a way that would hide all the branding etc.. is there any way to debug angular 2 routes.. like in laravel in the cli you can see what routes are active etc

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd but I haven't tried it yet myself (see also this ng-conf video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1YV9vJKXEA)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever comes across this - the inner templates wouldnt work because I was invoking RuntimeCompiler class to clear the template cache.. it worked when I was compiling my ts using just node tsc but for some reason when using it as part of a gulp workflow it totally broke the pages..